# Counting rows based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of multiple columns with the same set of tags like this:

```
id  |  tagone  |  tagtwo  |  tagthree  |
----------------------------------------
0   |  Action  | Adventure|   Rpg      |
1   |   Rpg    |  Action  |   Indie    |
```

There will never be multiple of the same tag in a row. What I want is to return a count of the elements for each tag. I want it to be independent of which column it was in and count each column. Like so:

```
Action    |2     |
Adventure |1     |
Indie     |1     |
Rpg       |2     |
```

Is there any way to do this in one query?

Comment: Do you have another table with all tags listed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bad data structure.  You should have a table with one row per id and per tag.

In the meantime, you can unpviot this:

```
select tag, count(*)
from ((select id, tagone as tag from t) union all
      (select id, tagtwo as tag from t) union all
      (select id, tagthree as tag from t) 
     ) tt
group by tag
```

Comment: do we need to select `id`s ?

Comment: @alex . . .  No, but the recommendation is to unpivot the data and this is how the tags would be unpivoted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
SELECT SUM(tagone='Action' + tagtwo='Action' + tagthree='Action) AS count
FROM MyTable
```

But I agree with @GordonLinoff, you should not store your tags across multiple columns. This is called [repeating groups, a conflict with First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

If you have a multi-valued attribute, you need another table. Then you can count in a more clear manner:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTableTags (
  mytable_id INT NOT NULL,
  tag VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (mytable_id, tag)
);

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTableTags
WHERE tag = 'Action'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT tags, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT t.id, t.tagone AS tags
      FROM table t
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t.id, t.tagtwo  
      FROM table t
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, t.tagthree 
      FROM table t
    ) t
GROUP BY tags;
```